# MyEclipse for spring 8.6 not starting

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When i start Myeclipse for spring 8.6 it shows below error.

```
jvm terminated. Exit code = -1
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
```

What could be the issue ?

Comment: Has it worked before? When was the last time it worked?

Comment: @AndreasDM: yes, it was working before.